# Convert multiple unequal lists from a file into a Python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have 50 lists in a py file and I am wondering if there's a way to import and make some of them into a dictionary - meaning only taking 48 lists into the dictionary. I can add it one by one through `dict(zip())` but this means that I need to provide a long list of the list names and the lists themselves. Is there a more scaleable way I can achieve what I want?

```
import a_py_file as a_py_file

fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon']
color = ['red', 'white', 'black']
location = ['Boston', 'Fiji']
name = ['John', 'Carter']
idk = ['D12323', 'A4343434']
...

one_dictionary = {

    'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon'],
    'location': ['Boston', 'Fiji'],
    'idk': ['D12323', 'A4343434']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir` (use it with caution, for internal use only because it's not really pythonic)

```
import a_py_file

EXCLUDE_LIST = ['color', 'name']

one_dictionary = {name: getattr(a_py_file, name) for name in dir(a_py_file)
                     if not name.startswith('__') and name not in EXCLUDE_LIST}

print(one_dictionary)

# Output:
{'fruits': ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon'],
 'idk': ['D12323', 'A4343434'],
 'location': ['Boston', 'Fiji']}
```